# jms - MappingJackson2MessageConverter setTypeIdPropertyName with runtime class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jms, spring-jms

I'm trying to create generic service that will handle sending messages to MQ using java 11, spring boot 2.2.6 and MappingJackson2MessageConverter. I want to use it as bean in my other services.

But when I send message it has interface's type instead of class of object that I'm sending.

I have interface `Entity` for all objects that I'm going to send and class `SomeEntity implements Entity`. So message has "type" of (for array) [Lcom.company.Entity; instead of [Lcom.company.SomeEntity;.

Interface for service:

```
public interface MessageSender<T> {
    void send(T[] entities);
}
```

Default implementation:

```
public class DefaultMessageSender<T extends Entity> implements MessageSender<T> {
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public DefaultMessageSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(T[] entities) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(entities);
    }
}
```

In other spring boot service I configure service as bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageSender<SomeEntity> customerMessageSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    return new DefaultMessageSender<>(jmsTemplate);
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("type");
    return converter;
}
```

Is there a way to force converter to use runtime class rather than interface's?

**Upd.:** There were 2 problems: type erasure that replaces all T with Entity class in DefaultMessageSender and arrays. SomeEntity[] is not a subclass of Entity[] and you cannot cast it.

To solve this I replaced array with list and made method abstract so I can redefine it with concrete classes.

```
@Bean
public MessageSender<SomeEntity> someEntityMessageSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    return new AbstractDefaultMessageSender<>(jmsTemplate) {
        @Override
        protected void send(List<SomeEntity> items) {
            var arr = items.toArray(new SomeEntity[0]);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(arr);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are sending an array.

You can set up a mapping from `Entity[]` to the concrete type (if there is only one), or subclass and override this method to peek at the element type.

```
    /**
     * Set a type id for the given payload object on the given JMS Message.
     * <p>The default implementation consults the configured type id mapping and
     * sets the resulting value (either a mapped id or the raw Java class name)
     * into the configured type id message property.
     * @param object the payload object to set a type id for
     * @param message the JMS Message on which to set the type id property
     * @throws JMSException if thrown by JMS methods
     * @see #getJavaTypeForMessage(javax.jms.Message)
     * @see #setTypeIdPropertyName(String)
     * @see #setTypeIdMappings(java.util.Map)
     */
    protected void setTypeIdOnMessage(Object object, Message message) throws JMSException {
        if (this.typeIdPropertyName != null) {
            String typeId = this.classIdMappings.get(object.getClass());
            if (typeId == null) {
                typeId = object.getClass().getName();
            }
            message.setStringProperty(this.typeIdPropertyName, typeId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, I can fill classIdMappings with something like ```Entity[].class, "[Lcom.company.SomeEntity;"``` but as you say it works only if I have single concrete class.